# $K = \left \{(a,b) \in \Bbb R^2 : \dfrac{a}{b} = 2 \right\}$ , $L = \left \{ (a,b) \in \Bbb R^2 : \dfrac ba = 3 \right\}$. Proof that $|K|=|L|$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

$K = \left \{(a,b) \in \Bbb R^2 : \dfrac{a}{b} = 2 \right\}$ , $L = \left \{ (a,b) \in \Bbb R^2 : \dfrac ba = 3 \right\}$.

Proof that $|K|=|L|$.

I know I should build a bijection between these two sets, but I can't seem to find the right way to do it. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Bijection: $f:K \to L$, $f(2x,x) = (x,3x)$.

Which gives $f(x,y) = (y,3y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$K = \{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | \frac{a}{b} = 2\},$
$L = \{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | \frac{b}{a} = 3\},$

then

$(2b,b) \in K$ and $(a,3a) \in L$

Let $(x,y) \in K \Rightarrow x = 2b, y = b$

Consider $f: K \to L$ as $f(2b,b) = (b,3b)$ then $f$ is bijective and $|K| = |L|$